# PHP way to find the web server's temp path?

Tags: php, upload, path

When you handle an HTTP upload the file is uploaded to

```
$_FILES['field_name']['tmp_name']
```

I know I could extract the temp path from there. But I was expecting maybe a `$_SERVER` param that had the temp path (there's none) or other elegant way of knowing it.

Is there any?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');
```

Comment: This is probably the more correct answer, as the upload temp dir may be different from the system temp dir.

Comment: As it is in the XAMPP distribution.

Comment: Be aware: not all web servers set `upload_tmp_dir`.  You're better off following @NateGlenn's suggestion of falling back to `sys_get_temp_dir()` if `ini_get('upload_tmp_dir')` returns an empty string.

Answer (score 20):

The function [`sys_get_temp_dir()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php) returns the directory path used by PHP to store temporary files.

Comment: Returns C:\Windows\TEMP\. My snippet returns D:/WAMP/tmp.

Comment: WAMP is preconfigured to use the tmp dir of the distribution.

Answer (score 8):

Using XAMPP on my private computer, the `ini_get` method worked great, since php.ini specifies the value `upload_tmp_dir`. However, after uploading to my employer's server, this code didn't work because the value apparently didn't exist in his server's php.ini file. So, I used the system's temp dir as the default, and now the script works on my computer and on his server:

```
$ini_val = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');
$upload_tmp_dir = $ini_val ? $ini_val : sys_get_temp_dir();
```

Comment: ...or `$upload_tmp_dir = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir') ?: sys_get_temp_dir()` in PHP 5.3 or later.

Answer (score 3):

I personally would use Sbm007's suggestion of:

ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');

As this takes into account apache per virtualhost settings like the upload_tmp_dir and open_basedir restrictions, where as :

sys_get_temp_dir()

Would only return the OS's specific temp directory, and if inside a multi-hosted environment could give you a directory you can't write to.