# Cannot upload image via move_uploaded_file

Tags: php

I am using code below to upload image via drag an drop system. Everything is ok, JS part is working well. But PHP part of code shows me error:

```
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(assets/img/photos/1657614494809.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www_root/_inc/upload.php on line 29, referer: https://smartobchod.sk/bazar/add.php
[Sat Jul 23 12:56:18 2022] [error] [client 78.99.32.1] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/home/gm016900/tmp/phpKaBL6m' to 'assets/img/photos/1657614494809.jpg' in /www_root/_inc/upload.php on line 29, referer: https://smartobchod.sk/bazar/add.php
```

**EDITED 25.07.2022** (added some security checks)

My PHP code in upload.php is:

```
<?php

// Get reference to uploaded image
$image_file = $_FILES["file"];

// Get image name
$image_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

// Get file size
$image_size = $_FILES["file"]["size"];

// Exit if no file uploaded or image name contains unvalid characters /, \\
if ( ( !strpos($image_name, '/') || !strpos($image_name, '\\') ) && isset($image_file) ) {
    $errors = array();
    $maxsize = 10485760;
    $acceptable = array(
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/jpg',
        'image/gif',
        'image/png'
    );
} else {
    die('No image uploaded.');
}

// Exit if image file is zero bytes or if image size is more then 10 MB
if (getimagesize($image_file["tmp_name"]) <= 0) {
    die('Uploaded file has no contents.');
} elseif ($image_size >= $maxsize) {
    die('Image is too large. Image must be less than 10 megabytes.');
}

// Exit if is not a valid image file or image has not supported type
$image_type = exif_imagetype($image_file["tmp_name"]);

if (!$image_type) {
    die('Uploaded file is not an image.');
} elseif ( !in_array($image_file["type"], $acceptable) ) {
    die('Image has not supported type JPG, PNG, GIF.');
} else {
    $src = "default.png";
}

// Get file extension based on file type, to prepend a dot we pass true as the second parameter
$image_extension = image_type_to_extension($image_type, true);

// Create a unique image name
$image_name = bin2hex(random_bytes(16)) . $image_extension;


// Location
$relative_location = "/bazar/assets/img/photos/".$image_name;

$absolute_location = dirname(__DIR__, 2).$relative_location;

$return_arr = array();

// transfer file created in tmp folder to location of pictures with name saved in address of $location
// in $image_file is stored $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]
if (move_uploaded_file($image_file["tmp_name"], $absolute_location)) {
    
    $src = $relative_location;

    $return_arr = array("name" => $image_name,"size" => $image_size, "src"=> $src);
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

This is sent in header to upload.php:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1657614494809.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Can you advice me what can be problem?

Comment: I think you forgot to put the temporary folder location in the code. The logic is to upload the image to a temporary folder and then move it to your assets foder

Comment: Please don’t take this as judgement, I’m just curious if you really write your code with comments preceding statements as shown in your sample. To your question, try concatenating `__DIR__` onto the destination to see what the absolute path is, and if that’s not correct, fix it. Also make sure that the path, including subdirectories, exist

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34128741/15770919
See if that can help

Comment: Try to set $location to a fixed full path spec. Maybe the relative path 'assets/img' attempts to drop the file in a not existing folder. Using the client-provided `$_FILES['file']['name']` for your filename is dangerous, an attacker may send you a filename like '../../../etc/passwd'

Comment: @ChrisHaas this is the correct answer. I changed address to ```"/home/gm016900/www_root/bazar/assets/img/photos/".$filename;``` and it is working, But I do not know how to write it to location with _DIR_ format and also address in return_arr is a little bit mess ```{"name":"1657614494809.jpg","size":321431,"src":"\/home\/gm016900\/www_root\/bazar\/assets\/img\/photos\/1657614494809.jpg"}```

Comment: I found something like this ```$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/bazar/assets/img/photos/' . $filename``` I do not know if exists some more flexible solution.

Comment: @user5329483 thanks for advice, how can I prevent this problem with $_FILES['file']['name']?

Comment: @Dump: Either disregard the given file name and do your own naming, or even simpler, just reject the upload completely if $_FILES['file']['name'] contains `'/'` or `'\\'`.

Comment: @user5329483 I added some security checks in my upload code and also image name generating part.

Answer (score 1):

Here I think your tmp/ folder permission is not proper so it is not able to read that folder or write just check /home/gm016900/tmp permission is should be gm016900 or it may not be created.

Comment: I checked tmp folder and there is 777 permissions. So it should be correct.

Comment: Please, see: [PHP way to find the web server's temp path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520956/php-way-to-find-the-web-servers-temp-path)

Comment: I checked it and it tmp folder is not my problem. But thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, you just need to keep track of relative vs absolute paths.

I wasn't able to test this code, but hopefully you should get the general gist if it fails. Instead of a single `$location` variable, I'm using two variables `$relativeLocation` and `$absoluteLocation`. The latter isn't actually needed, but it makes debugging much easier.

```php
/* Getting file name */
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

/* Getting File size */
$filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];

/* Location */
$relativeLocation = "assets/img/photos/".$filename;
$absoluteLocation = __DIR__.'/'.$relativeLocation;

$return_arr = array();

/* Upload file */
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $absoluteLocation)) {
    $src = "default.png";

    // checking file is image or not
    if (is_array(getimagesize($absoluteLocation))) {
        $src = $relativeLocation;
    }
    $return_arr = array("name" => $filename, "size" => $filesize, "src" => $src);
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Depending on where your function lives relative to the storage, you might need to go update a directory or two, or possibly go up and then back down:

```php
// Up one directory
$absoluteLocation = dirname(__DIR__).'/'.$relativeLocation;

// Up two directories
$absoluteLocation = dirname(__DIR__, 2).'/'.$relativeLocation;

// Up one directory then over to a sibling directory
$absoluteLocation = dirname(__DIR__).'/files/'.$relativeLocation;
```

As a personal preference, I always have a constant (or equivalent) in my projects that represents a known location on disk, and if I'm using a router script I define it there. That way, no matter how deep I get in nesting I can build my paths relative to that constant.

I also go one step further and use [this library](https://github.com/webmozart/path-util) (merged into [Symfony here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.1/src/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/Path.php)) to avoid string concatenation, not worry about whether something ends with a slash or not, and to be more cross platform. So my actual code looks like:

```php
$absoluteLocation = Path::join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'files', $relativeLocation);
```

Some people might think that's overkill, but once again it is just a personal preference.

Comment: Thanks. I need to use this solution ```$relativeLocation = "bazar/assets/img/photos/".$filename;
$absoluteLocation = dirname(__DIR__, 2).'/'.$relativeLocation;``` bcz in current time I have it placed in existing webpage. (I will move it on independend server later.) Then I will change it.